# Freeze / fixed header in GridView (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a gridview with dummy data in it. I would like to freeze the header on top while scrolling up and down.

This is my code but it does not work...

```
.grid {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;

}

.box {
    height: 520px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.mydatagrid {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px black;
    min-width: 80%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: White;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.rows {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

    .rows:hover {
        background-color: #5badff;
        color: #fff;
    }

.mydatagrid a /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS  **/ {
    background-color: Transparent;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .mydatagrid a:hover /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS  HOVER STYLES**/ {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }

.mydatagrid span /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS CURRENT PAGE INDICATOR **/ {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.pager {
    background-color: #5badff;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: White;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

.mydatagrid td {
    padding: 5px;
}

.mydatagrid th {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

This is a part of my GridView code:

```
    <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gvUsers" runat="server"
                    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"         
                    CssClass="mydatagrid" AllowPaging="False" 
                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                    OnRowDeleting="gvUsers_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="UserID"
                    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

When I use `position: fixed;` in my css the header styling breaks completely. See image below. I have also used `position: absolute` but still does nothing.

[image]

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. The gridview creates a table and you can't freeze the header on a table. The best you can do is create a separate table for headings and position it above the gridview/table. Ex: [How to make responsive table and header fixed both on same html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318758/how-to-make-responsive-table-and-header-fixed-both-on-same-html-table/47320108#47320108)

Comment: I am trying to make the header stay on top while you scroll. Unfortunately I can not get it to work